# Can't get 60fps on opacity transition in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, google-chrome-devtools, opacity

I'd like a 60fps or better opacity transition and am testing with Chrome dev tools timeline.  I've created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jnoody/Zt8nd/) to demonstrate, but basically it's just a div that has a class toggled every few seconds and transitions on opacity for the two states.  It looks fine to the eye, but I've been led to believe 60fps should be achievable.

HTML:

```
<div id="fader"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#fader {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}

#fader.fadeOut {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var fader = document.getElementById('fader');
setInterval(function () {
    fader.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
}, 2000);
```

I've tried the null transform hack, too, but either way it appears to be in its own layer (using "render composited border layers").

Comment: And, how are you measuring the fps?

Comment: Are you trying to say fadeOut and fadeIn 60 times in 1 sec? As @jfriend00 has asked, what's your frame length?

Comment: @sanjeevmk - look at the CSS.  The transitions are each 1 sec long.  fadeIn for 1 second, 1 second pause, then fadeOut for 1 second, etc...

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. Maybe the OP wants the transition to happen 60 times in 1 sec, that is, each transition of length 1/60s. And he could be confusing that thought with frames per second.

Comment: I'm measuring FPS with chrome dev tools frames timeline. I don't want the transition to happen 60 times in 1 second.  I want a 1 second transition to achieve 60fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if that helps, but I do get 60fps in the fiddle, going full window (that is appending /show to the fiddle)

[image: Chrome snapshot]

There is only one moment where the frame rate drops, but I believe it's when the javascript executes (so, nothing to do with posible GPU acceleration)